# C# TransactionScope class configuration

Tags: c#-3.0

We are using Transaction Scope for performing transactions in .Net 3.0. How do I configure it to use "Read Committed SNAPSHOT Isolation” Transaction as default?

Note: We are looking for a one place fix. i.e, a configuration entry for SNAPSHOT.

We need enterprise level configuration. We cannot go for each every place where Transaction Scope is used. Is there a application config file where we can change it?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I've merged your two accounts together. [Please read this Faq entry about cookie-based accounts.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44557/why-should-i-register-my-account/44562#44562) Also, StackOverflow isn't a forum; if you have a new question, please ask a new question. If you want to include more information in your question, please [edit it](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/5620833/edit). If you want to interact with one of the people who has answered, you can leave them a comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
var scope = new TransactionScope(IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted)
```

As per your update, try this instead:

```
var scope = new TransactionScope(IsolationLevel.Snapshot)
```

Check out [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.isolationlevel.aspx) on the `IsolationLevel` enumeration for more information.

**Update:**

AFAIK, you can't configure this at a settings-file level, simply because the `IsolationLevel` is dictated by construction of each instance of the type and external configuration for such things is extremely rare (off the top of my head I can only really think of one instance where this is possible with ASP.NET and controls, but not a single type).

Furthermore, `TransactionScope` is a `sealed` class, which means you can't inherit and extend its functionality to always construct a type with `IsolationLevel.Snapshot`.

You could create your own type, `SnapshotIsolationLevelTransactionScope` (for instance), and expose an `UnderlyingTransactionScope` property so that the functioning class you want to work with is available to callers - this would allow you to always construct the scope with the desired isolation level, but still requires you alter existing code and continue to use this type in the future where needed.

Comment: I've updated to try and provide both an answer and (possible, maybe not desirable) solution.